# Different Membership fee for each member

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Our organization have different membership fee (monthly) for each member which can be decided while signup or setup manually.
How can i achieve this ?
Is it possible to create a user dashboard item to display pending membership overdue ?

Jaisal

Comment: Thanks,
How to add this price set to already imported members ? Jaisal

Comment: Jaisal - i think you would be better to ask this as a new question and refer back to this one in your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [price set](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/membership-price-sets/) to create options for the membership type and include it on online membership page(Contribution Page).

The contact dashboard does display all membership and payment information for logged in user.

HTH

Pradeep