# Link Price sets to imported members

Tags: civimember

How to link price set to already imported members ? So that when a member login, they can see their membership fee overdue

Jaisal

Comment: Do you mean adding membership for imported contacts?

Comment: if you really mean Price Set (line items) then you may need to do an sql insert to get your data in to the database

Answer (score 1):

As Pradeep responded to your [original question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/different-membership-fee-for-each-member),  there is a  [contact dashboard](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#giving-users-the-ability-to-view-their-contact-dashboard) that will display information about a person's activity (e.g. contributions, memberships, etc.).

Syntax is important when asking questions - a price set is an entity that is used in conjunction with contributions and the contributions will have a given status. You specifically mention the "Overdue" status which is used with pledges, not with contributions - in your original question it sounds like what you want to use are contributions for membership payments (you can use either pledges or contributions, but not both).

You could create a [custom membership status rule](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/#membership-status-rules) called "Overdue" and have that be the status assigned to memberships that would otherwise be in "Grace" or "Expired" status, but on the contact dashboard, it will still be listed as "Expired / Inactive Memberships" (at the bottom of the first screenshot below) unless you have [word replacement](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology) in place. Before word replacement, the contact dashboard would look like this:

[image]

Using word replacement to replace the original text of "Expired / Inactive" with "Overdue", the dashboard will look like this:

[image]

If this was not the response you were looking for, please try to elaborate further.